# PHP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded IIS Overriding?

Tags: php, iis

I have a website running PHP 5.3, on IIS 7.
I'm getting the following error from PHP

```
Fatal Error: Maximum Execution Time of 10 seconds exceeded
```

I've checked the PHP.ini file, it's set to 300.
I've checked IIS CGI -> Timeout, it's set to 300.
I've checked all files included in the script for any overriding ini_set calls, set_time_limit calls, there are not.

Where could this 10 second limit be coming from?
Anyone?

**UPDATE**

I checked the phpinfo(), it shows the value as 600.  The way it should.

Comment: To get a better background on this, are you running in safe mode?

Comment: @taxicala, I'm not sure if I'm running in safe mode.  When I echo out ini_get('safe_mode') it shows nothing.  I added safe_mode=Off to the bottom of the php.ini too and restarted just to be safe.  Same Max Execution timeout error though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="200" />
</system.web>
```